# Axios create() error after vite build, show Axios is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, vue-router, vite

i have one project which using vite + vue3 + typescript.

It able to `npm run dev` and `npm run build`.

The error only occur on `npm run preview` and the only clue is this
`Axios is not a constructor`

Here is my vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa';
import { resolve } from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue(), VitePWA( )
    ],
    build: {
        target: 'esnext',
        sourcemap: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
            // into your library
            external: ["vue"],
            output: {
                // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
                // for externalized deps
                globals: {
                    vue: "Vue",
                },
            },
        },
    },

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~/': `${resolve(__dirname, 'src')}/`,
            '@': resolve('src'),
            'views': resolve('src/views'),
            '@components': resolve('src/@components'),
            'seedwork': resolve('src/infrastructure/seedwork'),
            'model': resolve('src/infrastructure/model'),
            "assets": resolve(__dirname, "src/assets"),
            "~assets": resolve(__dirname, "/src/assets"),
        }
    },
})
```

If facing this kind of error, how should i supposed to do the debug for this?

---

Found the cause, this might because my axios interceptor. Once i remove it and rebuild it, it will able to start the page and show the page. Right now i still dont have any idea why this one cause the error after `vite build`, but `vite` working just fine.

```
//main.ts

...
const noAuthHttpClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
});

const httpClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    }
});

axiosInterceptors.decorate(noAuthHttpClient);
axiosInterceptors.decorate(httpClient);

const roles = {
    "superAdmin": "Super Admin",
};
const config = {
    service: createService({ noAuthHttpClient, httpClient }),
    role: roles.superAdmin,
}
const router = createRouterFunction(config);
const app = createApp({
    render: () => (
        h(App)
    )
});


// app.config.globalProperties.$swal = Swal;
app.config.globalProperties.$messages = messages;
app.config.globalProperties.$service = config.service;
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the problem is because of the current AXIOS is not support for esm. Thus when run after build, Axios is not a constructor show up.

But i found the the redaxios is supported to build for that. Just dont have the interceptor, and the interceptor didnt merge in. I self create fork and update based on the previous commit.
Tested on my side thats working.

https://github.com/developit/redaxios/pull/75

If you guys could, help me to review and see where to improve. Thanks.